# VBA: Considering only the value of the last cell in A and extend selection untill W

Tags: vba, excel

I have several columns from A  to W. some aer full and some empty and some with "0", but i need to get the last value in A and  selecting from A17 untill W (LastValueOfA)

For example A is starting from rows 17,  B arrive untill 30 and W is full of 0 till the end of the sheet. I want a selection from A17 till W that stops where there is the last value of A and then copy or cut the values and append them on another sheet of the same file called "order inputs".

At the moment i only found the way to found and select the lastrow with values inside, but it consider all the columns obviously, not only A:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

LASTROW = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("a17:W" & LASTROW).Select
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure there are no values way down on the page in column A?  Add `Debug.Print LASTROW` and check column a where it states the lastrow is.

Comment: Are there formulas in Column A that could leave the cell 'blank'? Even if a formula's output is blank ( `""` ) doesn't prevent the cell from not being recognized as part of your `LASTROW` line.

Comment: Are the values in column A numbers, dates, text or text including zero-length strings?

Comment: In the column A the value is always text and can't be empty. Thanks

Comment: you could post a screenshot of your column A data last value "surroundings"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your last comments on @K.Davis answer, I guess your column A values are resulting out of a formula the value of which you consider to be valid when starting with "US"

So you may try this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change "Sheet1" to your actual sheet name
    .Range("A17:W" & .Columns("A").Find("US*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row).Select
End With
```

Comment: That's ti! Thanks. I was not noticed of the formula. They gave me this to do in 1 day and stupidly did not checked. Kudos to You.

Comment: I should also copy the selection and add it to another sheet in the sam file appending it on the first free row. I know that i must select the range and make a past special (and i know untill there) but how can I append it starting from the first free row?Thanks

Comment: as for the copy issue, don't `Select` anything (you almost NEVER need it) and use something along the lines of `..Range("A17:W" & .Columns("A").Find("US*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("MyTargetSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

Comment: Hi. Sorry to disturb You again. I deleted everything from the . select of previous working solution and replacing with the part from .Copy till offset(1). I changed the name in place of MyTargetSheet, but nothing happening. I also tried to empty the second sheet to see if it was replacing the previous value instead of adding them, but it stays white... nothing added then.

Comment: you have to code `.Range("A17:W" & .Columns("A").Find("US*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("MyTargetSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` right inbetween the `With ... End With` block

Comment: Hi @DisplayName. I Tried again with copy all the code and changing ("MyTargetSheet") with ("Order Inputs"), but the destination sheet is not appending, but is replacing what is already there. Maybe I was not clear on the beginning because of my bad english. I need to append to the first free cell after the last filled row, not to substitute the full content. Thanks again

Comment: What column in target sheet holds the “last value” to start pasting from?

Comment: always A. Thank you

Comment: then my suggestion should work (and in my tests it worked). should you have issues you may post a new answer along with your code and data example

Comment: Hi. Is pasting, but not appending, but removing the old value and replace them.infact  if I try to push the command button associated with the instructions, when the destination table is empty it fills all the rows correctly, but if I try when the table is already filled, I can see that is again at the same line I got when I am pasting on the empty table...

Comment: you'd better post a new answer along with this new issue, your code and data example

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to formulas that output an empty string. While the cell may *appear to be blank*, it's technically not. You need to search in the cell's **Values**.

You can use `Find()` to get around this.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Columns("A").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    MsgBox lastRow

End Sub
```

- `"*"` returns *any value* - it's just a wild card.
- `xlPrevious` will search from the bottom-up
- and finally, `xlValues` ensures you are looking at the *Cell's output* - not at the cell.

Comment: Thanks vor the very fast answer K.Dᴀᴠɪs! Sadly is making the same problem it select all the values untill the end of the sheet because of the 0 inthe W columns, while I'd like that would stop at the last row where there is a value on A (now is on the row 150 for example)

Comment: Thanks again, but still it tooks all the data untill the last line. All the text in A  begin with US... maybe this can help.

Comment: anyway the real problem is the all the column from R to W are full of 0 till row 9999. that is where it stops and also the msgbox confirms that